# "Not In" in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have the following Entity

```
public class Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

and have a list `List<Person> badGuys`

what I want to do is select from all persons except those in `badGuys` List

**My Code**

```
context.Persons
    .where(p => !badGuys.Contain(p))
    .ToList()
```

but I get an error

> Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this
>   context.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You could make an array containing the ids of the bad guys and filter out those ids (which are of a primitive type, so it should work):

```
var badGuyIds = badGuys.Select(x => x.PersonId).ToArray();

context.Persons
    .Where(p => !badGuyIds.Contain(p.PersonId))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: You could do it a little more efficient by removing the `.ToArray();` like so:
`var badGuyIds = badGuys.Select(x => x.PersonId);`
thus preventing a needless query on `badGuyId`, as the second query on `Persons` will do that anyway...

Comment: if I have badGuyIds list, and I want to right join and select badguys where not in Persons table, how to do that, Sir?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the clause ALL with the distinct(!=)

```
var badBoys= from P in context.Persons
         where badGuys.All(a => a.PersonId!= P.PersonId)
         select P;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can implement your own method to make necessary expression tree, like here:

```
    public static IQueryable<TEntity> WhereNotIn<TEntity, TValue>(
        this IQueryable<TEntity> queryable,
        Expression<Func<TEntity, TValue>> valueSelector,
        IEnumerable<TValue> values)
        where TEntity : class
    {
        if (queryable == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("queryable");

        if (valueSelector == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("valueSelector");

        if (values == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("values");

        if (!values.Any())
            return queryable.Where(e => true);

        var parameterExpression = valueSelector.Parameters.Single();

        var equals = from value in values
                     select Expression.NotEqual(valueSelector.Body, Expression.Constant(value, typeof (TValue)));

        var body = equals.Aggregate(Expression.And);

        return queryable.Where(Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(body, parameterExpression));
    }
}
```

And now you can call this extension method

```
var badGuys = new int[] { 100, 200, 300 };
context.Persons.WhereNotIn(p => p.PersionId, badGuys);
```

This method makes the same thing as:

```
context.Persons.Where(p => p.PersonId != badGuys[0]
                        && p.PersonId != badGuys[1]
                        . . .
                        && p.PersonId != badGuys[N]);
```

for each element of `badGuys` enumerable object.

An additional advantage of the method is its universality, cause you can call it for any property of any entity, f.e. `context.Persons.WhereNotIn(p => p.LastName, new[] { "Smith", "Brown", "Jones" })`.

Comment: That's a pretty solution but it's not a good one in terms of performance. I'd rather go for the ANY statement to increase performance. Plus, it's natively supported by EF so why not go for that approach?

Comment: @hbulens I'm not sure EF can process `Any` if it can't process `Contains` in the proposed context. But this is possible. As for performance, I think both queries will have similar execution plans at the DB level.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko this is a pretty, but hence I will have to user `p.PersonId` anyway for filtering, what would be the difference between your solution and @W0lf solution?

Comment: @MohamedBadr As I can see, there's no more differences.

Comment: well the SQL generated using your approach is like `WHERE (2 <> [Extent1].[PersonId]) AND (1 <> [Extent1].[PersonId])` while the code generated from @W0lf answer is like `WHERE  NOT ([Extent1].[PersonId] IN (2, 1))`  which query would be more efficient?

Comment: @MohamedBadr As I wrote above, I think the execution plans will be similar. The solution of w0lf is more clear, if you need to filter by single property.

Answer (score 0):

**LINQ to ENTITIES: NOT CONTAINS METHOD:**

The method should be `.Contains()` not .Contain. This requires a primitive type enumeration, so just enumerate your key field of your badGuys collection and call `.Contains()` on it in your `Where` clause when you query your context.

```
//get the list of bad guys
List<Person> badGuys = ...
//get simple primitive type enumeration
var badGuysIDs = badGuys.Select(t => t.PersonId).ToList();

using(Context c = new Context())
{
   var badPersons = c.Persons.Where(t => !badGuysIDs.Contains(t.PersonId)).ToList();
}
```

**LINQ TO OBJECTS EXCEPT() METHOD:**

Another option, if you already have your `List<Person>` of badguys is to use the `.Except()` method on your collection. This will have to be done after you enumerate your collection to objects.

```
//get the list of bad guys
List<Person> badGuys = ...

using(Context c = new Context())
{
   //enumerate Persons, then exclude badPersons
   var goodPersons = c.Persons.ToList().Except(badPersons);
}
```

**LINQ to ENTITIES EXCEPT() METHOD:**

The above method will not be ideal if you have a very large number of rows in your Persons table, because it will enumerate the entire collection. If you have a large number of rows, you will want to perform the exclusion on the database side before enumerating. To do this, you simply have to tell the database how to compare two objects for equality as in [This excellent SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7091963/4347337).

```
public class PersonComparer: IEqualityComparer<Persons> 
{
     public bool Equals(Person x, Person y) {return x.Id == y.Id;}
     public int GetHashCode(Person person) {return person.PersonId.GetHashCode();}
}


using(Context c = new Context())
{
    //get the list of bad guys
    List<Person> badGuys = ...

   var goodPersons = c.Persons.Except(badPersons, PersonComparer()).ToList();
}
```